# Cross join not recognized in HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQL ver 1.7. There is a part where I have a HQL like the following

String hql = "from ProductInv prodInv where prodInv.product.id in (:prodList)";

prodList contains list of product ids and the above hql is to get product inventories of the required product ids in prodList.

This hql is translated to a native sql query with "cross join". When this works against my actual db2, it works fine. But my unit tests based on HSQL fails. It says "cross join" is not a recognized keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade to one of the latest versions of HSQLDB (HSQLDB Versions 1.7.x are at least 7 years old).

If your version of Hibernate is 3.6 or later, use the latest HSQLDB (2.2.8 or later). For older versions of Hibernate, use 1.8.1.3.

Comment: I will try with recent version.

Comment: My JPA query is translated to `delete from A cross join B b_ where b1=?` and this is  supported neither by HSQLDB 2.3.3 nor by HSQLDB 2.5.0.

Comment: @Julien your JPA provider needs to be set up for HSQLDB

Comment: @fredt my JPA provider is configured with driver class name `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` and `hibernate.dialect`=`org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`.  Do I need something else ?

Comment: @Julien file a bug report at Hibernate site. The translation of the query that you reported contains a join in a DELETE statement, which is not supported by HSQLDB and is not allowed by the SQL Standard.