# Using hsqldb in unit test get sqlexception

Tags: hibernate, junit, hsqldb, junit4

I am using hsqldb 1.8 with hibernate 4.0 to do unit tests.
I have set in hibernate.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
```

I am using hql for the query.
Normally, i am using oracle db, my program runs well with it. But i try to use hsqldb for unit test, always get:

```
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890)
at myprogram.sgfratelimitingentities.SgfResourceDao.getTaskTypeID(SgfResourceDao.java:64)
at myprogram.UrlRoutine.getJobAndTaskType(UrlRoutine.java:186)
at myprogram.UrlRoutine.getJobTypeFromSeedFile(UrlRoutine.java:339)
at myprogram.UrlRoutineTest.testGetJobTypeFromSeedFile(UrlRoutineTest.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: CROSS in statement** [select sgftaskact0_.sgf_task_action_id as col_0_0_ from SGF_TASK_ACTION sgftaskact0_ cross join SGF_RESOURCE sgfresourc1_ where upper(sgfresourc1_.SGF_RESOURCE_NAME)=? and sgfresourc1_.sgf_resource_id=sgftaskact0_.SGF_RESOURCE_ID and sgftaskact0_.SGF_RESOURCE_REMOTE_COST=(select min(sgftaskact2_.SGF_RESOURCE_REMOTE_COST) from SGF_TASK_ACTION sgftaskact2_ where sgftaskact2_.SGF_RESOURCE_ID=sgfresourc1_.sgf_resource_id)]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcUtil.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:213)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
... 34 more
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513868/cross-join-not-recognized-in-hsql

Comment: @Octavio : this looks correct as CROSS JOIN is supported only in HSQLDB 2.X. Why not submit as an answer?